# Anchor tag using row id in bottlepy to-do tutorial

Tags: python, python-2.7, bottle

This is a template which takes rows of a database table and fields in separate fields. I am new to this.

```
  <table border="0" class="table table-hover">
        %for row in rows:
          <tr>
          %for col in row:
            <td>
              <b>
                {{col}}
              </b>
            </td>
          %end
          </tr>
        %end
        </table>
```

I wanted to use anchor tag with certain url with the id of the query in each rows above. How can i do that?

i.e. *http://domain.com/edit/**row id***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<!doctype html>
<table border="0" class="table table-hover">
%for row in rows:
  <tr>
  %for i in range(len(row)):
    <td>
     %# assuming you want to display col == 3 to as a link
     %# and the row id is in col == 0
     %if i == 3:
     <a href=" http://domain.com/edit/{{row[0]}}">{{row[i]}}</a>
     %else:
      <b>{{row[i]}}</b>
      %end
    </td>
  %end
  </tr>
%end
</table>
```